# Foundation Icon Takes Up Space But Is Not Visible. Why Not?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, glyphicons

1. Downloaded the zip file and unzipped it into my CSS folder. All files were shown in a green font, so I used the properties dialog box to remove the encryption.
2. Added the reference to my html document:

   `<link rel='stylesheet' href="css/foundation-icons.css" />`
3. Used an icon with the `<i class="fi-[icon]"></i>` suggested language.
4. The icon takes up space. It is in a button, so I can see the button get wider to accommodate it. But I don't see the icon itself, regardless of color or size setting. What's wrong?
5. The preview file works. But there was no instruction document that others have mentioned. Also, why in the preview file does it show not only the class but also what looks like an html entity, such as `&#xf100;`  ?

Comment: Seems that you've missed the font file.

Comment: In addition of my first comment, be sure that you are including well the `foundation-icons.[eot/ttf/svg/woff]` files (typography). If you use firefox, when you inspect the icon you can see in the inspector "Font" tab, that will help you to know if the font is used in the icon or not. I'm sure that's your problem

Comment: Why don't you use FontAwesome instead?  Superior selection of Icons.